# What is the correct way to set the variable smtpmail-auth-credentials?

Tags: emacs

using `smtpmail` with `emacs-mu4e`, I am trying to set the value of the variable `smtpmail-auth-credentials`.

If I set it to my `~/authinfo` , everything works fine, as expected.
If I try to set it as below:

```
(setq smtpmail-auth-credentials `(("smtp._my_server_.com" 123 "_my_email_@_mail_._com_" "_my_password_string_")))
```

I get an `AUTH error`.
Actually, I will retrieve later with `secrets-get-secret` ... but for now, even if I set it explicitly, things don't work.
I appreciate any help.

The exact error is:

```
smtpmail-send-it: Sending failed: 503 5.5.4 Error: send AUTH command first.
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your error, but you probably don't want to use a backtick in your snippet. That's like a quote, but for when you want to evaluate some things inside (using a comma `,`). Since you aren't evaluating anything, you should probably switch to a single quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(setq smtpmail-auth-credentials '(("mail.server.com" 587 "username" "password")))
```

With respect to this example, as compared to the example by the original poster, `username` is the name that precedes `@_mail_._com_` -- in other words, omit `@_mail_._com_`

Comment: Thank you lawlist... that was exactly the mistake.

Comment: FWIW, `smtpmail-auth-credentials` has been removed since Emacs 24.1. It seems users now have to put their passwords to `~/.authinfo[.gpg]`.